# setTimeout doesn't work intermittently on mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

```
$('.btn-activate').on('click touchstart', function() {
        $('.discount').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $({ countNum: parseInt($this.html())}).animate({
                    countNum: couponPercentage
                },
                {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing:'linear',
                    step: function() {
                        $this.html(Math.floor(this.countNum) + '% OFF');
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $this.html(Math.floor(this.countNum) + '% OFF');
                        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
                            if ($this.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
                                $this.css('visibility', 'visible');
                            } else {
                                $this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                            }
                        }, 200);

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                            if ($this.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
                                $this.css('visibility', 'visible');
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                });
        });
    })
```

In the `complete` block, a blinking animation is attempted to be achieved. This works, but on Safari Mobile there are times when the `setTimeout` doesn't seem to work because the blinking animation doesn't stop.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful. You are setting `refreshIntervalId` to be a global variable. That could cause problems if you are using `refreshIntervalId` elsewhere. Declare it like `var refreshIntervalId = ...` instead so that it's scoped within the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this had something to do with using `.on('click touchstart',...)`.

There is some sort of double triggering happening when the user taps on the button. After removing the redundant `touchstart`, I'm no longer able to replicate this.